# How can I fix my problem with merging channels in OpenCv in Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, merge, channel

I simply imported an image. 
I want to merge each BGR channel with zero arrays and then show them.
I've written my code as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread('./images/input.jpg')

B, G, R = cv2.split(image)

zeros = np.zeros((image.shape[:2]), dtype = 'int8')

cv2.imshow("Red", cv2.merge([zeros1, zeros1, R]))
cv2.imshow("Green", cv2.merge([zeros, G, zeros]))
cv2.imshow("Blue", cv2.merge([B, zeros, zeros]))

cv2.waitKey(500)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After running this code I get the following error.

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-9252d63ed763> in <module>
      7 zeros = np.zeros((image.shape[:2]), dtype = 'int8')
      8 
----> 9 cv2.imshow("Red", cv2.merge([zeros1, zeros1, R]))
     10 cv2.imshow("Green", cv2.merge([zeros, G, zeros]))
     11 cv2.imshow("Blue", cv2.merge([B, zeros, zeros]))

error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\merge.dispatch.cpp:129: error: (-215:Assertion failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function 'cv::merge'
```

It seems correct to me. what is the problem and how can I Fix this?

Comment: What is `zeros1` ? dont see it anywhere ... should be a `NameError`.

Comment: You could benefit from `zeros = np.zeros_like(B)` which gets you the same shape and dtype for little effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's the error:

```py
zeros = np.zeros((image.shape[:2]), dtype = 'int8')
```

dtype should be the same as the image so `uint8`.

BTW I think you want to just show the image and you don't care about merging?

Then you can just do the convert from GRAY to BGR with a single channel:

```
cv2.imshow("Red", cv2.cvtColor(R, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR))
cv2.imshow("Green", cv2.cvtColor(G, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR))
cv2.imshow("Blue", cv2.cvtColor(B, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR))
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
zeros = np.zeros((image.shape[:2]), dtype = 'int8')
```

change the `dtype` to `'uint8'`